# Which currently available rear derailleur would work as a replacement for a Schwinn Boundary 29 Pro Shift?

Tags: derailleur-rear, schwinn

I would like to change my rear derailleur. I have a Schwinn Boundary 29 inch, Pro Shift. I am not sure what year. Which currently available derailleur would mount up to the frame and operate correctly with my rear derailleur?

[image]
From https://www.walmart.com/ip/Schwinn-29-in-Boundary-Mens-Mountain-Bike-Black-and-Green/302140001 showing a 1x7 speed drive train.

Comment: What Derailleur do you have at the moment, and why do you change it?

Comment: I've added more info on this specific bike based on the model name.  Does it match your bike, with 7 cogs in the back and one on the front ?